# Golf Transmission

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

As in, the 5 speed transmission from the original VW Golf GTI.

Print the transmission pattern in as few bytes as possible.

Yes I know this isn't what it actually looks like but the GTI 5 speed shift knob pattern is a lot worse.

```
1  3  5
|  |  |
|--|--|
|  |  |
2  4  R
```

Comment: Is extra whitespace that doesn't affect the image's presentation acceptable?

Comment: @noodleman A trailing newline is generally acceptable

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't clear enough, I'm referring to having e.g. trailing whitespace on each line, or a consistent amount of leading whitespace on each line. Many ascii-art challenges allow this so I was wondering if it's applicable here.

Comment: yeah extra whitespace is fine sure

Comment: “the GTI 5 speed shift pattern looks a lot worse” citation-needed

Comment: @noodleman from a golfing perspective. It's got reverse in the top left and has R 1 3 5 on top and 2 4 in the middle below which makes it a lot less symmetrical

Comment: Yeah, fair enough

Answer (score 9):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 25 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
7Ç%3?-:°U+'|³+°UÃ·û Õr6'R
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=N8clMz8tOrBVKyd8syuwVcO3%2byDVcjYnUg)

<s>Japt <sub>beats</sub>ties with Jelly!</s> The Jelly submission has improved a lot, but unfortunately I don’t think this solution can.

I'll explain this part by part as it's a bit hard to visualize without seeing the in-between results.

```
7Ç%3?-:°U+'|³+°UÃ·­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
7Ç                  # ‎⁡For each number from 0 to 6:
  %3                # ‎⁢  Take it modulo 3.
    ?-              # ‎⁣  If it's truthy (nonzero), return a dash "-".
      :             # ‎⁤  Otherwise:
       °U           # ‎⁢⁡    Increment variable U (starts at zero).
         +'|³       # ‎⁢⁢    Append "|" three times.
             +°U    # ‎⁢⁣    Append U incremented again.
                Ã   # ‎⁢⁤End map over range.
                 ·  # ‎⁣⁡Join this list on newlines.
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

This gives:

```
1|||2
-
-
3|||4
-
-
5|||6
```

Next, `û` centers each line:

```
1|||2
  -  
  -  
3|||4
  -  
  -  
5|||6
```

And `Õ` transposes the rows and columns:

```
1  3  5
|  |  |
|--|--|
|  |  |
2  4  6
```

Finally, `r6'R` replaces the final 6 with "R" to get the proper image:

```
1  3  5
|  |  |
|--|--|
|  |  |
2  4  R
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>26 25</s>  24 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string)!

```
6s2j€”|$⁺Zj"⁾ -KŒBḤ¤YṖ”R
```

A full program that prints.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@s2CjrUdOaRw1za1QeNe6KylJ61LhPQdf76CSnhzuWHFoS@XDnNKBk0P//AA)**

#### How?

```
6s2j€”|$⁺Zj"⁾ -KŒBḤ¤YṖ”R - Main Link: no arguments
6                        - six
 s2                      - split into twos     -> [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
   j€”|$                 - join each with '|'  -> [[1,'|',2],[3,'|',4],[5,'|',6]]
        ⁺                - repeat that         -> [[1,'|','|','|',2],[3,'|','|','|',4],[5,'|','|','|',6]]
         Z               - transpose           -> [[1,3,5],['|','|','|'],['|','|','|'],['|','|','|'],[2,4,6]]
                   ¤     - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
            ⁾ -          -   [' ', '-']          -> [' ','-']
               K         -   join with spaces    -> [' ',' ','-']
                ŒB       -   bounce              -> [' ',' ','-',' ',' ']
                  Ḥ      -   double (vectorises) -> ["  ","  ","--","  ","  "]
                            - (multiplying each character by 2 in Python)
           "             - zip with:
          j              -   join              -> [[1,"  ",3,"  ",5],['|',"  ",'|',"  ",'|'],['|',"--",'|',"--",'|'],['|',"  ",'|',"  ",'|'],[2,"  ",4,"  ",6]]
                    Y    - join with newlines  -> [1,"  ",3,"  ",5,'\n','|',"  ",'|',"  ",'|','\n','|',"--",'|',"--",'|','\n','|',"  ",'|',"  ",'|','\n',2,"  ",4,"  ",6]
                     Ṗ   - pop (remove the 6)
                         - implicit, smashing print
                      ”R - 'R'
                         - implicit print
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `5Ṿ€;”Rs2j€”|$⁺Zj"⁾ -KŒBḤ¤Y` ties. Hard to think of anything to bring that idea to 25 though.

Comment: Not so hard for me since the only reason I had used `Ṿ€` rather than `R` was because the implementation of `¦` does not ignore errors for elements not being affected and `»` cannot compare ints and chars.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
⁶⸿⸿↑Ｅ⪪2143R5²⟦⟦⪫ι|||
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMNM05oLwlKKKYopUoJzrUILdBR8Ews0ggtyMoGyRoYmxkGmSjoKRpo6CtHRXvmZeRqZOgpKNTU1SpqxsZqa1v///9ctywEA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⁶
```

Output `6` `-`s to the canvas.

```
⸿⸿
```

Move to the start of the line below next.

```
↑Ｅ⪪2143R5²⟦⟦⪫ι|||
```

Loop over `21`, `43`, `R5`, inserting `|||` between each pair, and output vertically and triple-spaced.

Answer (score 4):

## APL+WIN, 47 bytes

```
5 7⍴(,⍉(7⍴2)⊤⎕av⍳'II⌷II')\'135||||--|--||||24R'
```

[Try it online!Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tv6mC@aPeLRo6j3o7NUAsI81HXUuAahLLHvVuVvf0fNSz3dNTXTNG3dDYtAYIdHVBCAiMTILU/wON4PqfxsUFAA)

Explanation:

```
⎕av⍳'II⌷II' Convert characters to integers 73 73 127 73 73 

,⍉(7⍴2)⊤ Convert to boolean matrix, transpose and flatten to a vector

 1 1 1 1 1
 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0
 1 1 1 1 1
 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0
 1 1 1 1 1

 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
 1 0 0 1 0 0 1

 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1

 This vector has as many 1s as the characters to be displayed.

 \'135||||--|--||||24R'  Inserts spaces into the character vector  corresponding to the 0s

1  3  5|  |  ||--|--||  |  |2  4  R

5 7⍴ Reshapes output as a matrix
```

Trivial answer for 41 bytes

```
5 7⍴'1  3  5|  |  ||--|--||  |  |2  4  R'
```

Comment: I don't know any APL but I tried moving some of the code around and it looks like this is constructing a matrix of every slot where characters should be placed, and filling them in? That's a really interesting method I never would have thought of. Maybe there's a way to golf the string being filled in? It does have a whole repeated section.

Comment: @noodleman I have added an explanation to show what is going on. I have not yet managed to reduce it. Perhaps some Apler can improve it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 154 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 19.25 bytes

```
\|3*5ɾ\RJ2ẇvj\-dd½½YføĊ§
```

(24 bytes SBCS)

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwiXFx8Myo1yb5cXFJKMuG6h3ZqXFwtZGTCvcK9WWbDuMSKwqciLCIiLCIiXQ==) |  | [-6 bits with `L`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9TCIsIiIsIlxcfDMqNcm+XFxSSjLhuod2alxcLWRkwr3CvVlmw7jEiiIsIiIsIiJd)

Optimizing this was a fun process, especially with Vyncode!

Bitstring:

```
0110101010001111001101000011000011101011101011110001101000001010010011110100010010101010100111111110100100011011101101100010011011010001010111110000101110
```

```
\|3*5ɾ\RJ2ẇvj\-dd½½YføĊ§­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
\|3*                      # ‎⁡Push `|||`
    5ɾ\RJ                 # ‎⁢Append "R" to range [1,5]
         2ẇvj             # ‎⁣Split into chunks of length 2, join by "|||"
             \-dd½½       # ‎⁤Double "-" twice, halve twice (Push [["-","-"],["-","-"]])
                   Yf     # ‎⁢⁡Interleave and flatten
                     øĊ§  # ‎⁢⁢Centre, transpose and join by newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 36 bytes

```
/a/  //b/
|a|a|
/1a3a5b|--|--|b2a4aR
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/Xz9RX0FBXz9Jn6smEQi59A0TjRNNk2p0dUEoySjRJDHo/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>52</s> 51 bytes

Boring, straightforward answer. Prints to STDERR.

```py
exit("1  3  5\n|  |  |\n|--|--|\n|  |  |\n2  4  R")
```

In a REPL, or Notepad & PHP (39 bytes), or paper (0 bytes), we can shorten that to this:

```py
'''1  3  5
|  |  |
|--|--|
|  |  |
2  4  R'''
```

Comment: Do the site rules permit you to drop the "print("?

Comment: Now that you say that, it could count as an anonymous string, which is referenced to by adding a `f=\ ` (omit the space) in the header, which is allowed for anonymous *functions*. I'm not sure whether rules permit us to make our submission an anonymous string.

Comment: I am arguing that, entered straight in the Python REPL, the string will print out the right answer as requested. Whether this permitted depends on local rules.

Comment: Well then, that's a submission for a Python REPL, not a Python interpreter. I'll include that as well though

Comment: The REPL method would work the same in Notepad or TextEdit but with less input. The task is to _"Print the transmission pattern in as few bytes as possible."_ Taken literally, you can do that with a pencil on a piece of paper, using zero bytes of computer memory.

Comment: Can you use PHP to save bytes?  [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724IKNgwYKlpSVpuhY31Q0VFIwVFEy5ahQUQIirRlcXhOB8IwUFEwWFIIhyqC6YbgA)

Comment: If output to `stderr` instead of `stdout` is acceptable, save a character changing `print` to `exit`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 53 bytes

```haskell
"1  3  5"++a++"|--|--|"++a++"2  4  R"
a="\n|  |  |\n"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ0W0km5yQYFS7OI025ilpSVpuhY3TZUMFRSMFRRMlbS1E7W1lWp0dUEIyjNSUDBRUAhS4kq0VYrJq1FQAKGYPCWI5rW5iZl5tgWlJcElRSppELEFCyA0AA)

The boring 45 byte answer:

```haskell
"1  3  5\n|  |  |\n|--|--|\n|  |  |\n2  4  R"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ0W0km5yQYFS7OI025ilpSVpuhY3dZUMFRSMFRRMY_JqFBRACMjQ1QUhJBEjBQUTBYUgJYimtbmJmXm2BaUlwSVFKmkQsQULIDQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 35 bytes

```
1x3x5y|--|--|y2x4xR
y
¶|x|x|¶
x
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sKLUkMy9xwYKlpSVpuhY3VbkMK4wrTCtrdHVBqNKowqQiiKuS69C2mgogPLSNq4JLQWFJcVJyMVQLTCsA)

The last line contains two spaces. Replaces the input the fixed string `1x3x5y|--|--|y2x4xR`, then replaces `y` with `¶|x|x|¶`, where the pilcrows are newlines, and finally replaces `x` with two spaces.

### Old Answer, <s>45</s> 39 bytes bytes

```
135$&7*|24R
.
$&  
3`\|
|--|--|
L`.{9}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sKLUkMy9xwYKlpSVpuhY31bkMjU1V1My1aoxMgrj0uFTUFBS4jBNiarhqdHVBiMsnQa_asnZJcVJyMVQTTDMA)

-6 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602)

#### How it works

1. Ignored the input and replaces it by `135`, 7 `|`s (we actually need 9, but these are inserted in step 4) and `24R`
2. Replaces every character by itself, followed by two spaces
3. Replaces the third pipe (0-indexed) by `|--|--|`
4. Formats into lines of 9 characters each

Comment: [-6 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8vQ2FRFzVyrxsgkiEuPS0VNQYHLOCGmhqtGVxeEuHwS9Kota///BwA)

Comment: [Alternative 35](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sKLUkMy9xwYKlpSVpuhY3VbkMjU0rKyqNTIK4KrkObaupqTm0jUuPS8VAQYGrgqtGVxeElhQnJRdDtcC0AgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>28</s> <s>25</s> 24 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0'|…|--)û.B7δ∍»¾5L'Rªι.;
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9vc2FiaWX//zAnfOKApnwtLSnDuy5CN8604oiNwrvCvjVMJ1LCqs65Ljv//w)

**Explanation:**

```python
0          # Push "0"
 '|       '# Push "|"
   …|--    # Push "|--"
       )   # Wrap all three values into a list
        û  # Palindromize it: ["0","|","|--","|","0"]
.B         # Box it: add trailing spaces to make all strings the same length:
           #  ["0  ","|  ","|--","|  ","0  "]
   δ       # Map over each string:
  7 ∍      #  Extend it to length 7:
           #   ["0  0  0","|  |  |","|--|--|","|  |  |","0  0  0"]
     »     # Join by newlines:
           #  "0  0  0\n
           #   |  |  |\n
           #   |--|--|\n
           #   |  |  |\n
           #   0  0  0"
¾          # Push 0
 5L        # Push list [1,2,3,4,5]
   'Rª    '# Append "R"
      ι    # Uninterleave it into two parts: [[1,3,5],[2,4,"R"]]
       .;  # Replace every first 0 one by one with the flattened values of this list
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: I think your second version is a bit closer to @mathscat’s Vyxal submission than it is to my Japt. They are both pretty similar to each other though.

Comment: @noodleman I've already got a different approach than both of my initial answers. :)

Comment: Ooh, this is really nice! Very clever thinking to use repeat-to-length for that. I’m going to try this method in Japt but I think it’ll come out to closer to 30 bytes.

Comment: Actually, it didn’t work because Japt doesn’t have a translate builtin.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 55 bytes

Another one of those boring answers:

```js
console.log(`1  3  5
|  |  |
|--|--|
|  |  |
2  4  R`)
```

I am aware the shaving off the pair of those pesky parentheses saves 2 bytes, but sadly the result is not as requested.

Trying to do some *actual* cool golfing performs worse (**<s>59</s> 56 bytes in this case from noodle man**):

```js
console.log(`1  3  5${v=`
|  |  |
`}|--|--|${v}2  4  R`)
```

(No Try It Online button because you can run the snippets right here!)

Comment: *cool* version JavaScript, 56 bytes: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGCpaUlaboWNy2S8_OK83NS9XLy0zUSDBUUjBUUTFWqy2wTuGoUFECIK6G2RlcXhIDCtUYKCiYKCkEJmhD9UGNgxgEA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 41 bytes

Unfortunately, the shortest I could create was simple a string of the required output... quite boring I know!

```powershell
"1  3  5
|  |  |
|--|--|
|  |  |
2  4  R"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8lQQcFYQcGUq0ZBAYS4anR1QQjON1JQMFFQCFL6/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## C# .NET 6, <strike>152</strike> 146 bytes

```csharp
int a=124,b=45,c=10;foreach(var x in new[]{49,0,51,0,53,c,a,0,a,0,a,c,a,b,b,a,b,b,a,c,a,0,a,0,a,c,50,0,52,0,82})Console.Write((x>0?(char)x:"  "));
```

Edit: Stored 124 '|', 45 '-', and 10 '\n' into vars to eliminate a char each call

Comment: Isn't this a snippet, not a program or function? [Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet) [Meta 2](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/1146#1146)

Comment: Nope, that's a full program now that top-level statements exist.

Comment: Ah, interesting! Someone at Microsoft must be into code golf ;)